How to get the last message for each conversation for sender and recipient
I know these kinds of questions have been asked before but my question has some different requirements.
I need to select the latest message from the conversation where
user is either the sender or recipient.
Messages are encrypted but to make sure that
my website provides more security the sender and recipient both
are hashes not the actual ids of those users.



id
sender
recipient
message
created_at




1
abc
bnn
mmdms
176589776


2
nmd
abc
dsdsd
176872877


3
bkl
abc
dsdsd
176879877


4
sds
nmd
dsdsd
176879977


5
abc
bnn
ssdsd
179879977


6
nmd
abc
nmnsds
179879977



As I've have already told, I want to select the last message of a particular user with other users. The user can either be sender and reciepient. Important thing is that I also want to select message with only those recipients which are in Where clause because a user can have messages with 1000 other users and selecting all of those 1000 messages won't be efficient performance wise.
This is the demo of how I want the result set. For this example, I am selecting the message for user abc with other users and get the result set like this.



id
sender
recipient
message
created_at




3
bkl
abc
dsdsd
176879877


5
abc
bnn
ssdsd
179879977


6
nmd
abc
nmnsds
179879977



I tried many SQL queries Joins, sub-query but none of them worked. Here is one of them,
select messages.* 
                from 
                    messages
                  join 
                    (select sender, max(created_at) messages  
                        from 
                           (
                             (select id, sender, recipient, created_at 
                               from messages 
                               where user=? ) 
                           union 
                             (select id, sender, recipient, created_at
                               from messages
                               where recipient IN (?,?,?))
                            ) t1
                       group by user) t2
                 on ((sender=? and recipient=?) or 
                     (sender=? and recipient=?)) and 
                     (created_at = m)
               order by created_at desc

It didn't work I tried this one too but it is so basic and didn't get me the desired results,
SELECT msg, iv FROM messages 
             WHERE (sender=? AND reciepient IN (?,?,?,?)) 
             OR (sender IN (?,?,?,?) AND reciepient=?) ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1"

I've been attempting to construct this query for weeks, but I'm still unable to get it right. I want to know how to construct this query. Thanks in advance for an answer.

Isn't the logic just a simple "for a distinct sender and recipient, get the last message"?

What is the diff between "user", "owner", recipient", "etc?  I would expect ther to be only "sender" and "recipient".

@Eric I don't know how to do it, if you can answer then it will be really helpful. I want the query to be optimized.

Use groupwise-max to find last.  Do that for and as sender, then as recipient, then `UNION the results.  If necessary, do another groupwise_max

@RickJames can you post it as an answer my SQL skills are not that good right now. Thanks
